# LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs does not allow Azure URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to setup a Redirect URL inside of the LinkedIn OAuth configuration. Any website that I add that contains azurewebsites.net in it does not work. Is there any way to resolve this issue or work around it?

Comment: Have the same problem. I have the app that was created in december, and it was possible to use *.azurewebsites.net urls for OAuth, but yesterday, when I tried to update collection of urls, I realized that I can't apply changes with *.azurewebsites.net in the list! What's happened guys? Why did nobody notify about this?